# Navigating in both directions in one2one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am using AspNetIdentity and with that the generated model for AspNetUser.
I have created my own AspNetUser class like so:

```
 public class MieterverwaltungUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TenantData TenantData { get; set; }
}
```

The TenantData is not mapped because I don't want it to be shown in the table and only use it for navigation purposes in my code. 
TenantData however has a reference to it:

```
 public class TenantData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    public MieterverwaltungUser MieterverwaltungUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to select a User and include the TenantData like so:

```
var user = await _mieterverwaltungContext.Users.Include(x => x.TenantData).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email.ToUpper());
```

But I am getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside
>   Include is not valid.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the `[NotMapped]` Annotation and adding

```
public int MieterverwaltungUserId { get; set; }
```

in `TenantData`, so that EFC knows where to put the foreign key. Now I can use the code above without problems.